# Create a new document using MEAN mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

i'm new to mongoose and mongodb, i'm trying to create a new document inside my collection.
I'm able to update existing one or get all the document from the collection.
I need to create a new document based on the collection (**I have a single collection now**). - createMoment function.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://url and pass');
var usersSchema  = require('./users_schema').usersSchema;
mongoose.model('usersM', usersSchema);
var usersAction;

mongoose.connection.once('open',function(){
  var Users = this.model('usersM');
  var query = Users.find();
  query.where('userId');

  query.exec(function(err, docs){
    usersAction = docs;
    console.log("docs: " + usersAction);
    return usersAction;
  });

});

exports.getData = function(){
  return usersAction;
};

exports.createMoment = function(_fn, _ln, _conc,_lan,_lat,cb){
  var Users = mongoose.model('usersM');
  console.log("createMoment Called");
  Users.insertOne({
        'leadRank':1,
        'adminApproval':true,
        'userFname':_fn,
        'userLname':_ln,
        "conclusion":_conc,
        'tentCoor':{'latitude' : _lat, 'longitude' : _lan}
    }, null, function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Inserted a document into the users collection.");
        cb(result);
    });
};
```

My schema:
**I'm not passing some of the fields yet**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema;

var usersSchema = new schema({
  campName: {type:String, required:true},
  centerCoor: [{
    latitude:{type:Number},
    longitude:{type:Number}
  }],
zoom: {type:String},
users: [{
  leadRank: {type:Number},
  adminApproval: Boolean,
  userFname: {type:String, required:true},
  userLname: {type:String, required:true},
  conclusion: {type:String},
  tentCoor: [{
    latitude:{type:Number},
    longitude:{type:Number}
  }]
}]
}, {collection: 'camps'});
exports.usersSchema = usersSchema;
```

Comment: Aren't you getting an exception about `insertOne` not being a function? You should be calling `create` instead.

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes you are correct, now i have to change my callback function

Comment: So, what you call a `moment` on your function's `createMoment` name is actually a document inside your `users` Array, right?

Comment: @charliebrownie yes, i mentioned that i didn't wrote here all of the feilds in here, the : campName: {type:String, required:true},
  centerCoor: [{
    latitude:{type:Number},
    longitude:{type:Number}
  }],
zoom: {type:String},
 is hardcoded for now.

Comment: I can see that you mentioned that, but giving functions and variables significative names can help other people to understand quicker what you are doing (without having them to get into the details). So, having your Array named `users` and your function `createMoment` at first made things not that clear... as if you had your array named `moments`, for example. I assumed it was the same because I got to read carefully your code :-)

Comment: Anyway, there's a mongo operator called `$push`, when working with arrays, that will insert your doc into `users`: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/